# Encrypt a passsword using a pentaho job and store in file

Tags: linux, windows, pentaho

here i have to create a job which coverts the plain text to encrypted password using below syntax

Windows:

```
Encr.bat -kettle <password>
```

Linux:

```
./encr.sh -kettle '<your-password>'
```

Note: the main problem I'm facing is i have to execute these commands inside data-integration folder alone.
Please hemp me out in this.
here i'm not sure of the location where its in server.

I tried to find the location of the folder using find command

```
./encr.sh -kettle '<your-password>
```

have to find the exact location of data-integration folder and execute command line command in this folder path

Answer (score 0):

You can find the file executing this command:

**Linux:**

```
find / -name encr.sh
```

**Windows:**

```
dir encr.sh /s /p
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks ,yah this is fine but here i'm automating the process one job have to execute the commands and store file in specified location